# Dynamic default_target_path on Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm developing an application with Symfony2 and FOSUserbundle.

When a user logs in on the system I want to redirect them to /user/username, were username obviously change with every user.

One option of Security.yml is default_target_path. Is it possible to set default_target_path to a dynamic path or I need to override the class of FOSUB on charge of login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overwrite [SecuredController](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_controllers.md) and [Templemate](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_templates.md).
In controller when user is login, create variable and pass it to your templemate

```
<input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="{{redirect_url}}" />
```

Comment: Ok, I trying to do ti that way. But as I'm quite new to PHP I'm a little bit stuck.

Is there a proper way to modify the Login form or should I copy & paste FOSUB's login form and add the hidden input inside the form?

Comment: @Axxis You can create your form. Read Security part in documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The answer above is wrong, you have to register a service as the success_handler for your firewall implementing AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface (you can mimic DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler)

right answer here: [Symfony2 extending DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15918617/symfony2-extending-defaultauthenticationsuccesshandler)