# Symfony2 how to pass parameters to auth success handler

Tags: authentication, symfony, service

when symfony2 authenticates user by login form, an event `security.authentication.success` is fired and is handled by `DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler`. Constructor of this object takes two arguments `HttpUtils $httpUtils` and `array $options`. Variable `$options` is not empty and contains configuration options from `security.yml` like:

```
login_path => pkr_blog_admin_login
user_referer => false
...
```

I created a service `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` that extends `DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler` but can't find a way to pass values from `security.yml` as $options to constructor of my object. How can I do this?

I had tried using xdebug step by step debugging to see how those options are passed to `DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler` but couldn't find exact place in code :/

//EDIT

I found out that this configuration is set in `src/Symfony/Bundle/SecurityBundle/DependencyInjection/Security/Factory/AbstractFactory.php` and **only for default handler**.

Here are some comments about not getting configuration from `security.yml` in custom handler:

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/5432
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/5488

Anyone know a way to get configuration parsed and ready to use by default handler from within my handler?

I suppose that it might be done by passing service container to my handler. I'll try this when I'll be back from work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>It seems that only way to make it work is to use compiler pass and change default handler class. See my similar question:</strike>

Better way of doing this is to use service as event handler:

[Symfony2 extending DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15918617/symfony2-extending-defaultauthenticationsuccesshandler)