# Symfony 2 extending DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler

Tags: authentication, symfony

I'm trying to count failed and successful logins for my users. For that, I simply want to increase the respective counter in the datebase whenever an authentication attempt succeeds or fails. But I want to keep the default behavior without reinventing it.

So I followed this post: [Symfony2 hold behavior when extending DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17850262/symfony2-hold-behavior-when-extending-defaultauthenticationsuccesshandler)

But apparently I cannot add any parameters to the constructor of my subclass of DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler or Symfony complains that the argument types are wrong.

How can I inject my user management service as a constructor parameter??

EDIT: Actually, the problem seems to be a little bit different! I have the following line in my services.yml:

```
services:
 security.authentication.success_handler:
  class: %security.authentication.success_handler.class%
  arguments: [@my_stuff.my_user_management_service, @security.http_utils, {}]
```

But the second argument passed to the constructor is an array containing the options like "login_path". But it's supposed to be an instance of HttpUtils. I'm confused...

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by myself: the order of the parameters is important. I had to move my_stuff.my_user_management_service to the end of the parameter array like so:

```
arguments: [@security.http_utils, {}, @my_stuff.my_user_management_service]
```

I don't really understand why, though. There is something wrong with the parameter injection. Maybe someone has some insight??

Comment: if you dislike keeping the order then you can use named arguments like arguments:
    $firewallName: 'members_fe'

Answer (score 0):

As far I can see, there is much simpler NOT to override DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler
but to use Event Listener:

```
class Auth2FaEmailListener extends AbstractObjectEventSubscriber
{
    use EnabledTrait, TargetPathTrait;

    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            TwoFactorAuthenticationEvents::SUCCESS => 'onSuccess',
        ];
    }


    public function onSuccess(TwoFactorAuthenticationEvent $event)
    {
        if (!$this->isEnabled()) {
            return;
        }
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        
        // do what you need
    }
}
```

Remember to register Listener service:

```
// in SomeBundle/Resources/config/services.yml 
SomeBundle\EventSubscriber\:
        resource: '../../EventSubscriber'
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```

Feel free to see the list of available events:

- Older version: https://github.com/scheb/two-factor-bundle/blob/4.x/Resources/doc/events.md
- Current version https://symfony.com/bundles/SchebTwoFactorBundle/current/events.html