# Getting doctrine dbal is null on app initialization

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.3, dbal

I was using Authentication success handler to populate some values on session on every success login. I wanted some database operation to be done so i pass @doctrine.dbal.default_connection from my config file. Here is my config file where i override success_handler function.

```
services:     
    security.authentication.success_handler:
    class:  XYZ\UserBundle\Handler\AuthenticationSuccessHandler
    arguments:  ["@security.http_utils", {}, @doctrine.dbal.default_connection]
    tags:
        - { name: 'monolog.logger', channel: 'security' }
```

In AuthenticationSuccessHandler.php my code is like this...

```
namespace Sourcen\UserBundle\Handler;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\HttpUtils;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Connection;


class AuthenticationSuccessHandler extends DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

private $connection;

public function __construct( HttpUtils $httpUtils, array $options, Connection $dbalConnection ) {
    $this->connection = $dbalConnection;
    parent::__construct( $httpUtils, $options );
}

public function onAuthenticationSuccess( Request $request, TokenInterface $token ) {
    $response = parent::onAuthenticationSuccess( $request, $token );
    // DB CODE GOES  
    return $response;
}
}
```

This is working when i execute some controller URL directly. But when i execute my app home url like "www.xyz.com/web" it throws following error...

```
 Catchable fatal error: Argument 3 passed to XYZ\UserBundle\Handler\AuthenticationSuccessHandler::__construct() must be an instance of Doctrine\DBAL\Connection, none given, called in /opt/lampp/xyz/app/cache/prod/appProdProjectContainer.php on line 1006 and defined in /opt/lampp/xyz/src/Sourcen/UserBundle/Handler/AuthenticationSuccessHandler.php on line 18
```

Any idea how it can be solved ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to extends the `DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler`class.

Try to define your service class like:

```
namespace XYZ\UserBundle\Handler;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\InteractiveLoginEvent;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Connection;


class AuthenticationSuccessHandler  {

private $connection;

public function __construct( Connection $dbalConnection ) {
    $this->connection = $dbalConnection;
}

public function onAuthenticationSuccess( InteractiveLoginEvent $event ) {
    $user = $event->getAuthenticationToken()->getUser();

    // DB CODE GOES  
    return $response;
}
}
```

and configure your service tagged to the event listener component `security.interactive_login`

```
services:     
    security.authentication.success_handler:
    class:  XYZ\UserBundle\Handler\AuthenticationSuccessHandler
    arguments:  [@doctrine.dbal.default_connection]
    tags:
        - { name: 'kernel.event_listener', event: 'security.interactive_login'. method:'onAuthenticationSuccess' }
```

PS: Why don't you use the `doctrine.orm.entity_manager`instead of `doctrine.dbal.default_connection`? (In my sf i haven't this service dumped in the `php app/console container:debug` command)

Comment: Hi matteo, sorry i couldn't reply as i was sick. actually i tried to implement it but failed. so i made my constructor argument from 'Connection $dbalConnection' to 'Connection $dbalConnection = null' and it stopped throwing error. Is there any practical tutorial on using authentication success handler with db connection ? i was new to symfony and not able to exactly understand why the above you gave was not working in my current setup!! thank you so much for helping :)

Comment: Hi @JosephRanjanSRanjanS, have you try my solutions? In summary: you don't need to extend any class: simply define an event listener and tag it to the symfony defined event. If I find some additional resources (tutorial etc) about it i will inform you