# Symfony2 FosUser override login_check

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm working with `Symfony` and `FosUserBundle` and I need to insert a log in my database if login is ok and before the redirection to my secured area.

I already overrode `SecurityController` for `loginAction`, but where can I insert my log ?

I don't think it's in `loginAction`, but I don't know how can I override `login_check` ?

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can doing the work indirectly with symfony layer framework. If it's good for you that use symfony you can :

- use the DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler class symfony and read this : [DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15918617/symfony2-extending-defaultauthenticationsuccesshandler)
- declare a service symfony with function 'onAuthenticationSuccess'

After that you can work with all symfony tools for logging all of you want.

**I already use this method with FOSUserBundle.**

Comment: Yeah thanks, I overrode onAuthenticationSuccess and it's ok ! I know it's another question butI have a user in_memory, how can I check if it's a user in_memory in onAuthenticationSuccess ? I don't want to log if it is...